# What is meant by "Database Validation"

Tags: c#, database

I have encountered two statements I cannot understand from the book : MCSD CERTIFICATION TOOLKIT (EXAM 70-483)

This block of text contains those statements:

Making the database validate its data can prevent the program from saving invalid data and is important, but in some sense it’s also a last resort. "Many programs perform a considerable amount of work with data before it is saved to a database, so there are opportunities for the data to become corrupted between the user’s input and the database."
"Programs also use data stored in the database later to perform calculations and that provides other opportunities for the data to become corrupted." Finally, some programs don’t use databases at all.

I cannot understand the statement:
"Many programs perform a considerable amount of work with data before it is saved to a database, so there are opportunities for the data to become corrupted between the user’s input and the database"

And: 
"Programs also use data stored in the database later to perform calculations and that provides other opportunities for the data to become corrupted."

Please explain these statement to me. Does it mean that after performing the processing on the data, the data is not suitable to be stored in the database?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the word *corrupted* is probably a little bit.. apocalyptic. They would be better off using the phrase *inconsistent with the expected formats, ranges or values*.

Without reading the book I would suggest they are talking about using INSERT and UPDATE triggers as a mechanism for validating (and rejecting) data  before it is committed to a table.

An example of data becoming corrupted between an application's UI and the database is an address. These can be notoriously difficult to store in a consistent and coherent fashion, especially when it is largely input in free form by an end user. Your code would then accept it, try and massage it a little, make sure it fits certain broad criteria (like there is a street number, that there is 'street' or 'avenue' or 'road' in the address, etc.), then you will save it - most likely across several database fields. In the process it could be easy for the address to become inadvertently mangled, too long, line (field) breaks in the wrong place, etc. One way to ensure this data isn't persisted in a bad format is to use a final level of validation at the database level.

Answer (score -1):

"Programs also use data stored in the database later to perform calculations and that provides other opportunities for the data to become corrupted."

Why is this recommended because, many times we work in layered structure and UI layer is only responsible for accepting values, business layer is for data processing and DAL to save the data. So when data is passing through various layers and data processing it might get corrupt and we don't want to take that risk because once data is in database there will be no mechanism to track what went wrong.

Comment: Hi Dnyanesh,  thhank you very much. So you are saying that it is converting the values to a form suitable for the database that can corrupt the data?It is such heavy conversions that may corrupt the data? Is this because when we take data from UI, we may have to represent it in a completely different datatype to validate it and store it into the database?

Comment: Please correct me in case I have written something incorrect.

Comment: @user3509153 Yes whatever you are saying is possible. At times we changes the to convert it in db suitable, at times we convert it in some format and we might rap it up with some operation.So that is possible.